# Arrays in a PHPUnit Flat XML Dataset

Tags: testing, phpunit, dbunit

In PHPUnit I am trying to test that two arrays are equal: one from the function I am testing and one from a Flat XML dataset.  However, the array that the function generates has an additional array nested inside it, and I don't know how to include an array in the XML Dataset to mirror it.  Is it possible to do so, or will I have to find a workaround?

This is what the output of my PHPUnit test looks like:

```
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
     0 => Array (
         'FLCT_alt' => 'asfda'
-        'composers' => Array ()

@@ @@
         'FLCT_alt' => 'ksksksks'
-        'composers' => Array ()
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need some simple testing, you can check ids in the first array, element counts etc... to avoid the need for the sub array to be tested.

```
$this->assertEquals(5, count($ArrayVariable));

$this->assertArrayHasKey('FLCT_alt, $ArrayVariable);
$this->assertEquals('ksksksks', $ArrayVariable['FLCT_alt']));
```